# How to check whether a menu item is marked with SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW

Tags: android

I was wondering, how can we check whether a `MenuItem` is marked with `SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW`?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item 
        android:id="@+id/menu_add"
        android:title="@string/menu_add"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:icon="?attr/actionBarAddIcon"/>
    <item 
        android:id="@+id/menu_search"
        android:title="@string/menu_search"
        android:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/collapsible_searchtext"
        android:icon="?attr/actionBarSearchIcon"/>
```

For instance, given the above XML, how can I know `MenuItem` with id `menu_search` is having `SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW`

`MenuItem` has `setShowAsAction`. However, it doesn't have something like `getShowAsAction`

Comment: But, MenuItemImpl is only meant for internal usage. Also, there is no guarantee the implementation class of MenuItem is MenuItemImpl. It can be ActionBarsherlock's implementation